# responseJSON json parse in Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am getting json form server. But json parsing nil in swift. Here is my json

```
{
    "out_code":"0",
    "out_message":"0",
}
```

I tried bellow code to out_code using Alamofire & swiftjson

```
func getData(){
    
    Alamofire.request("url", method: .post,parameters: [
        "request_code":"11"
        
    ]).responseJSON{(responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value != nil)){
            
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            print("swiftyJsonVar==",swiftyJsonVar)
            
            if let v_id = swiftyJsonVar["out_code"] as? String {
                print("out_code----",v_id)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**swiftyJsonVar==** in print like bellow

```
{
    "out_code" : "0",
    "out_message" : null
}
```

But I did not get data from **out_code** key. Please help me what is wrong with my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using SwiftyJSON library.

Casting for each type is been handled from the library. Try using the following code instead of casting to `String`:

```
if let v_id = swiftyJsonVar["out_code"].string {
    print("out_code----",v_id)
}
```